# Is it a premature optimization to use std::move()?

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have the following code:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> strs;

    std::string var("Hello World");
    // Make some modifications to 'var'
    strs.push_back(std::move(var));
}
```

The part of the sample I want to point out is the usage of `std::move()`. Basically I'm worried about a copy on the `push_back()` call. Suppose the string I'm adding is really big. I'm still learning C++11 r-value references, so I'm not sure how the compiler would optimize away the copy (if at all) without the `std::move()`.

Could anyone explain if this is a premature optimization (forcing moves in all cases where you want to avoid copies, in general)? If so, what patterns should I expect the compiler to follow (or most likely follow) that would result in an optimized and automatic move here?

## EDIT

I want to add that I understand how automatic moves happen on *function return values*, because NRVO/RVO applies. The specific example I gave here wouldn't apply RVO, so I'm uncertain.

Comment: `move` really only makes sense if the function called is let's say *move aware* (and the type supports move semantics.) In this case, the function you are calling is not, and so you will gain nothing from this. If however you were calling a *move aware* function (say `emplace_back()`), then it makes sense to use `std::move()`. Same principle applies to any of your custom functions, types etc.

Comment: @Nim is that necessarily true? I was considering a scenario where a temporary is move-constructed (from the forced r-value returned by `std::move`), and then that would be passed into push_back() as an r-value (const ref). Is this scenario wrong?

Comment: @Nim Since when is `push_back` not move-aware?

Comment: @Nim Also push_back has an overload for r-value reference (although I'm not sure it matters for this specific example): http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back

Comment: aargh, my bad, take my second comment in the context of a general move aware function, I removed my earlier comment (can't edit the one above..)

Comment: If its not the simplest code that gets the job done, its premature optimization.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

*The other answers focus too much on the technical aspects of the question for my taste, so I will try to give a more general answer.*

In short: No, using a "trick" like std::move in the way it's described in the question isn't a premature optimization. Not using `std::move` when it can be used is fine too, unless the code is already known to be performance critical.

The need to avoid premature optimization is sometimes understood as "don't optimize, until you can prove it's necessary", but I prefer to read it as: "don't waste time solving problems unless you know they need to be solved".

Premature optimizations require spending effort in order to optimize what may not need to be optimized, and usually transform a simple problem into a complex problem while doing so. From that perspective, I would classify any long pondering of the question itself as premature optimization.

A related example: People working in performance critical code will often pass arguments as const references ( `const std::string&` ). Because that's what they are used to do, they will use the same pattern in code that isn't performance critical, even though they could just use pass-by-copy ( `const std::string`, or even `std::string` ). That isn't a premature optimization either.

Comment: +1: *From that perspective, I would classify any long pondering of the question itself as premature optimization.*  If unconditionally using a fast approach is easier than determining whether a slow approach would also work, then unless one has reason to believe that some theoretical advantage of the slow approach might be important, ascertaining whether one could use the slow approach to leave open its theoretical advantages could represent a different form of "premature optimization" [not for speed, but potential flexibility].

Comment: I agree in this case. The one count against this is that moving from `var` *might* make it somewhat harder for readers of the code to reason about the state of `var`. The same is true of anything that mutates `var`, of course, doing so via the result of `move` isn't special. But if using `move` causes you to not mark some object `const` that otherwise could be, then you might get into an area where the *possibility* of a speed-up is less value than keeping things conceptually simple (assuming immutable values are simpler, which I claim is often true).

Comment: @SteveJessop Agreed. While std::move adds a declaration of intent, and a possible optimization, there are many variations of the example where std::move can add unnecessary confusion, complexity, and/or risk. In the end, r-value programming is a learned skill just like const correct programming.

Comment: @Peter Concerning your last paragraph, passing by const reference when you do not need to mutate the object is a good best practice, regardless of the importance of performance at that site. This would basically start a discussion on premature pessimization which I won't go into, but it almost sounds like you're saying that passing a vector in as a copy (example) when it won't be modified is acceptable practice. I don't necessarily agree with that. Correct me if I've misunderstood.

Comment: @Robert Yes, in places where many of the developers are not too familiar with C++ and usually work in languages without const, I think this can be acceptable. Not good practice, but acceptable. Now, experienced C++ developers writing code without regard for const correctness? That's not acceptable practice.

Comment: It was a tough call but I'm marking this one as the answer despite the fact that it does not have the most upvotes. The highest voted answer certainly answers the question, however I feel like after reading everything, I get the most takeaway value from this one. Not only does this address my concern with premature optimization with `std::move`, but it provides good general outlook that can be applied elsewhere. Also the comments/discussion here adds a lot of helpfulness/value as well. Thanks to everyone for your contributions and thought.

Comment: It just occurred to me that the whole idea of needing these move semantics at all, only exists because of the problem C++ created. C can't really have this problem because you have to program the idea of knowing what your pointer is pointing to and only make copies when you specifically do so because the compiler is never going to call anything like a copy constructor on your behalf, just because you returned a local variable.

Answer (score 28):

> I'm not sure how the compiler would optimize away the copy (if at all) without the `std::move()`.

Only a *very* clever compiler could optimise that away, so if the copy could be expensive (e.g. a very long string) then it is better to move it.

Without the move the code is effectively a sequences of calls to:

```
strlen  // count "Hello World"
malloc  // allocate memory for string var
strcpy  // copy data into var
malloc  // re-allocate vector
free    // deallocate old vector
malloc  // allocate new string
strcpy  // copy from var to new string
free    // destroy var
```

With the move it becomes:

```
strlen  // count "Hello World"
malloc  // allocate memory for string var
strcpy  // copy data into var
malloc  // re-allocate vector
free    // deallocate old vector
```

In theory a smart compiler could do that transformation automatically, but for the compiler to see through all the layers of abstraction introduced by the constructors and destructor and the `vector` member functions is quite difficult, so proving that the code could be transformed to remove a `malloc` and `free` is complicated.

Answer (score 20):

After `std::move`, the original object, in this case `var`, must be in a valid state but could hold any value, e.g. it might be empty.

If you know you are not going to use `var` and you only created it to put into the `vector` then it isn't really "premature" optimisation as the intention of what you are trying to do.

`vector` has a new method `emplace_back()` which is the same thing but clearer, and uses forward-arguments (here you just do `emplace_back("Hello World")` if all you are doing is constructing it). In your case as you are "making some modifications with var" `emplace_back` isn't likely to not be appropriate.

In old `C++` you could optimise the copy by doing `push_back()` on an empty string then swapping it.

Comment: Before `emplace_back` was introduced, how would you implement the same functionality, i.e. resize and construct in place? I guess that mechanism is different than `std::move`.

Comment: The compiler should know when a variable is not used anymore especially in this simple case and just insert the `move` or even construct the string directly inside the `vector`. Therefore one could argue that this micro optimization should not be done manually.

Comment: @nwp - How could the compiler do that in the general case? _We_ know how `string` behaves, but how could the compiler know that, e.g., `var`'s destructor won't have different behavior depending on whether or not it was `move`d?

Comment: @JoshKelley By looking at the implementation of the move constructor and destructor. There are edge cases where the compiler cannot know for sure but 99.9% of the cases are obvious. That said I believe compilers are not smart enough yet so manual `move` is the way to go for now.

Comment: @nwp, the compiler would not look at the move constructor. Optimizers do not look at the source code of other functions and see if they are equivalent and could be used instead, the optimizer would work at a lower level (the compiler's AST or similar) and see that malloc+memcpy+malloc+memcpy+free can be transformed to just a malloc+memcpy, which would have the effect of constructing the string directly in the vector

Comment: Before emplace_back there was no forwarding of arguments I assume. But the "efficient" non-copying push_back is resize() then swap.

append then modify the one at the back would have an issue if anything is going to throw and leave it there in a bad state. resize() might bad_alloc but the swap is safe.

Comment: @Jonathan: But `string` uses an allocator, and the standard allocator, I believe, tends to be more complicated than just invoking malloc and free.

Comment: @Hurkyl, not necessarily. For libstdc++ and libc++ `std::allocator<T>::allocate()` just calls `::operator new` which just calls `malloc`, and `std::allocator<char>::construct()` is trivial. I don't know what the MS allocator does.

Answer (score 18):

I don't know why everyone is suggesting you use `emplace_back()`. The purpose of `emplace_back()` is to avoid copy/move operations by constructing the object in place. In this case, you have already constructed the object, so at least 1 copy/move is unavoidable. There is no advantage to using `emplace_back()` over `push_back()` in this case.

Otherwise, I agree with everyone else saying that it's not a premature optimization because the move semantics models what you are trying to do more closely than making a copy of the object.

Comment: Not sure why you only have my upvote - this is a good answer IMHO. The `// Make some modifications to 'var'` part of the OP makes `emplace_back` useless here.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: But one can use `emplace_back` to construct and append a new string in-place, call `back()` to get the reference to the newly created string and modifies it then.

Comment: @C.R: you can, although that trick often makes it harder for your code to implement the strong exception guarantee when acting on an externally-visible vector. If the modification to the string fails (in particular throws) then you need to undo the `emplace_back` change you already made. Of course, when the vector is local there's no such problem, but I think it means people tend to ignore the trick rather than worry about whether it's safe in context. In practice it's less dangerous than people might think, since use of `anything_back` commonly does several such, so needs attention already.

Comment: @C.R. I generally like to avoid "cute" stuff like that, it violates the KISS principle. I like to keep code simple, natural, and self-documenting as a first priority. If it becomes a bottleneck based on real measurements, then I will consider "tricks". But it doesn't make sense to use them right away.

Comment: @RobertDailey: I hardly consider this a trick or unnatural. But indeed I failed to account for the strong exception guarantee as Steve mentions, so maybe it is not a good idea after all.

Comment: I think this should rather be a comment under an answer or a suggestion to an answerer rather a stand-alone answer.

Comment: I'd say the *purpose* of `emplace` is to enable explicit conversions. The avoidance of moves is an added benefit. Avoidance of copies isn't an issue, since `insert` and `push_back` also have rvalue overloads.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is premature optimization if it is premature optimization.

Let me elaborate:
Premature optimization is defined by whether you are optimizing a part of the code that you don't know to be performance critical. That is, premature optimization is never defined by the method of optimization, it is always defined by the place of optimization and your knowledge about what you are doing.

---

Now, to the advisability to optimize using `std::move()`:

With `std::move()` you avoid the heavy lifting of copy construction, like memory allocation, deallocation, copy constructing contained elements, deconstructing contained elements, etc. That is good. But one part remeains: the construction/destruction of the container object.

`emplace_back()` has the virtue of entirely avoiding the construction of the temporary object. So, whenever you can avoid a temporary object by using `emplace_back()`, you have a small win.

Considering code quality (read readability/maintainability): `std::move()` has the downside of leaving you with an unusable object, which can be a source of bugs. This does not happen with `emplace_back()`. So, again, the later is clearly preferable.

Of course, `emplace_back()` cannot be used in all contexts that allow the use of `std::move()`. So, if these are performance critical, `std::move()` may be the way to go. There are some very valid use-cases for optimization with `std::move()`. However, you might also find out that you can write the code in a way that does not require any copy/move/emplace construction at all. Never stop looking for a better solution when optimizing!

In the end, it remains that the validity of optimizing with `std::move()` depends entirely on the context: It is good optimization wherever it is good optimization.

Comment: The tautologies are just noise.

Comment: premature optimization is doing something non-intuitive that doesn't show intent and you wouldn't normally want to do but you think it will make the code faster or optimal in memory usage etc.

Comment: vector<bool> is a clear case of premature optimization, trying to optimize is memory-use..

Comment: @CashCow `vector<bool>` can well make the difference between a running program, and a program that becomes victim to the OOM-killer. Also, it can well make the difference between a runtime of 1 or 32 seconds. However, it depends entirely on the use-case whether `vector<bool>` is an optimization or not. In most programs that use `vector<bool>` it *will* be premature optimization. But `vector<bool>` is a special case: it's within a library, and libraries must be optimized for *all* relevant use cases (if they are optimized at all). And a factor of 32 is too big an optimization to pass by.

Comment: @cmaster: your comment already contains the reason why `vector<bool>` is extremely bad - with "bad" beeing: that this tradeoff is forced on every user of `std::vector`, whether they like it or not. The optimization in `vector<bool>` is undoubtedly important, but simply presented under the wrong name! A better (and consistent) name would be something along the lines of `dynamic_bitset`…